# Accessing /Differences array with PoDoFo

Tags: c++, pdf, podofo

This question is a specific question about the [PoDoFo](http://podofo.sourceforge.net/) library.

How do I access the `/Differences` array entry in the Encoding dictionary of a Font resource?

After I read the font name from the `Tf` operator, I can get the font through `PoDoFo::PdfPage::GetFromResources`. However, while the `PdfFont` class has `PoDoFo::PdfFont::GetEncoding`, I cannot see how you would get to the `/Differences` array from there.

From the PDFSpec (I'm only worried about Type 1 Fonts):

> Encoding
>
> (Optional) A specification of the font’s character encoding if
>   different from its built-in encoding. The value of Encoding shall be
>   either the name of a predefined encoding (MacRomanEncoding,
>   MacExpertEncoding, or WinAnsiEncoding, as described in Annex D) **or an
>   encoding dictionary that shall specify differences from the font’s
>   built-in encoding or from a specified predefined encoding** (see 9.6.6,
>   "Character Encoding").

Does this mean the `PdfEncoding` object returned from `PoDoFo::PdfFont::GetEncoding` contains the differences array (if there is one)?

(I've asked on the PoDoFo mailing list a little while ago, but posting here to see if someone with knowledge of `PoDoFo` and pdfs can help).

Answer (score 2):

PoDoFo knows many different kinds of encoding classes, cf. the encoding object factory:

```
if (pObject->IsName ())
{
    const PdfName & rName = pObject->GetName ();
    if (rName == PdfName ("WinAnsiEncoding"))
        return PdfEncodingFactory::GlobalWinAnsiEncodingInstance ();
    else if (rName == PdfName ("MacRomanEncoding"))
        return PdfEncodingFactory::GlobalMacRomanEncodingInstance ();
    else if (rName == PdfName ("StandardEncoding"))      // OC 13.08.2010
        return PdfEncodingFactory::GlobalStandardEncodingInstance ();
    else if (rName == PdfName ("MacExpertEncoding"))     // OC 13.08.2010 TODO solved
        return PdfEncodingFactory::GlobalMacExpertEncodingInstance ();
    else if (rName == PdfName ("SymbolEncoding"))        // OC 13.08.2010
        return PdfEncodingFactory::GlobalSymbolEncodingInstance ();
    else if (rName == PdfName ("ZapfDingbatsEncoding"))  // OC 13.08.2010
        return PdfEncodingFactory::GlobalZapfDingbatsEncodingInstance ();
    else if (rName == PdfName ("Identity-H"))
        return new PdfIdentityEncoding ();
}
else if (pObject->HasStream ())     // Code for /ToUnicode object 
{
    return new PdfCMapEncoding(pObject);
}
else if (pObject->IsDictionary ())
{
    return new PdfDifferenceEncoding (pObject);
}
```

> *(PoDoFo/src/doc/PdfEncodingObjectFactory.cpp)*

You are interested in the last case. Thus, if the encoding object you have at hands is an instance of PdfDifferenceEncoding, you can use:

```
/** PdfDifferenceEncoding is an encoding, which is based
 *  on either the fonts encoding or a predefined encoding
 *  and defines differences to this base encoding.
 */
class PODOFO_DOC_API PdfDifferenceEncoding : public PdfEncoding, private PdfElement {
 public:
[...]
    /** 
     * Get read-only access to the object containing the actual
     * differences.
     *
     * \returns the container with the actual differences
     */
    inline const PdfEncodingDifference & GetDifferences() const;
[...]
};
```

> *(PoDoFo/src/doc/PdfDifferenceEncoding.h)*

`PdfDifferenceEncoding` is declared in the same header class and offers some interesting methods:

```
/** A helper class for PdfDifferenceEncoding that
 *  can be used to create a differences array.
 */
class PODOFO_DOC_API PdfEncodingDifference {
    struct TDifference {
        int         nCode;
        PdfName     name;
        pdf_utf16be unicodeValue;
    };

    typedef std::vector<TDifference>                 TVecDifferences;
    typedef std::vector<TDifference>::iterator       TIVecDifferences;
    typedef std::vector<TDifference>::const_iterator TCIVecDifferences;

 public: 
    /** Create a PdfEncodingDifference object.
     */
    PdfEncodingDifference();

    /** Copy a PdfEncodingDifference object.
     */
    PdfEncodingDifference( const PdfEncodingDifference & rhs );

    /** Copy a PdfEncodingDifference object.
     */
    const PdfEncodingDifference & operator=( const PdfEncodingDifference & rhs );

    /** Add a difference to the object.
     * 
     *  \param nCode unicode code point of the difference (0 to 255 are legal values)
     *
     *  \see AddDifference if you know the name of the code point
     *       use the overload below which is faster
     */
    void AddDifference( int nCode );

    /** Add a difference to the object.
     * 
     *  \param nCode unicode code point of the difference (0 to 255 are legal values)
     *  \param rName name of the different code point or .notdef if none
     */
    void AddDifference( int nCode, const PdfName & rName );

    /** Tests if the specified code is part of the 
     *  differences.
     *
     *  \param nCode test if the given code is part of the differences
     *  \param rName write the associated name into this object if the 
     *               code is part of the difference
     *  \param rValue write the associated unicode value of the name to this value 
     *
     *  \returns true if the code is part of the difference
     */
    bool Contains( int nCode, PdfName & rName, pdf_utf16be & rValue ) const;

    /** Convert the PdfEncodingDifference to an array
     *
     *  \param rArray write to this array
     */
    void ToArray( PdfArray & rArray );

    /** Get the number of differences in this object.
     *  If the user added .notdef as a difference it is 
     *  counted, even it is no real difference in the final encoding.
     *  
     *  \returns the number of differences in this object
     */
    inline size_t GetCount() const;

 private:
    struct DifferenceComparatorPredicate {
        public:
          inline bool operator()( const TDifference & rDif1, 
                                  const TDifference & rDif2 ) const { 
              return rDif1.nCode < rDif2.nCode;
          }
    };

    TVecDifferences m_vecDifferences;
};
```

> *(PoDoFo/src/doc/PdfDifferenceEncoding.h)*

Comment: Thanks for the help. My biggest problem was not knowing how to traverse through the objects in the pdf, I found out you can get to the underlying font object with `GetObject` and them from there get to its encoding entry by calling `GetIndirectKey("Encoding");`. Although I feel like the PoDoFo could be restructured better.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a pointer to a `PoDoFo::PdfFont`, you can get to the underlying object with a call to `GetObject` since it inherits it from [PoDoFo::PdfElement](http://podofo.sourceforge.net/doc/html/classPoDoFo_1_1PdfElement.html#a91dcb533bedd09e8c0a858dbc37bb594). From there call `GetIndirectKey("Encoding")` to get a pointer to the Encoding dictionary which contains the differences array and pass that to the `PoDoFo::PdfDifferenceEncoding` constructor.

```
PoDoFo::PdfObject* fntobj = fnt->GetObject();
if (fntobj)
{
    PoDoFo::PdfObject* fntdic = fntobj->GetIndirectKey("Encoding");
    if (fntdic)
    {
        PoDoFo::PdfDifferenceEncoding diff(fntdic);
        PoDoFo::PdfArray diffarray;
        PoDoFo::PdfEncodingDifference d(diff.GetDifferences());
        d.ToArray(diffarray);
    }
}
```